# sqlite text field read as blob in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

**hi 

i reading a string from sqlite database and got a force close with this message :**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(4338): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
```

**is use this code to reading from database :**

```
String lastname = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("lastname"))
```

**also my database field is "Text" and not blob**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue from the Manifest typing feature of SQlite. If you encrypt a text and that text contain none-character chars, with saving that text to database field automatically recognize as blob. for prevent with this error we can get fetching the data as text inside of catch if error occurred we continue to fetch as blob data insode of exception section.

Answer (score 0):

You should recreate your db and clean your project and run